# Keepass Master Password not working after rebuild

Tags: windows, windows-10, keepass

Having just recovered from a major crash I have rebuilt my computer. Previously it was running Windows 10 on a Raid configuration. Now it is running on non-Raid Windows 10, freshly downloaded. Apart from the drive changes and the software changes the rest is as before,
As you have probably guessed, Keepass no longer recognises my Master Password. I am confident that I am using the correct password so I am expecting there to be some files not properly restored. I have extensive backups available...but can anyone guide me on a reliable recovery process for Keepass in this situation?

Thanks for the help

George

Comment: Without the password the database cannot be accessed

Comment: Make sure the Keepass installation is fine (download a fresh installer from [the website](http://keepass.info/)) and compare your DB to one you're sure that would work or just use one from your backup directly. Are you sure the password is correct? You didn't have a compound key e.g. by using a keyfile and you didn't use your windows account in combination with it?

Comment: I used a fresh Keepass download and I have tried several different versions of my original database. There is no doubt about the Master Password. I am getting the feeling that there is some lock between Keepass and the installation environment and that my changes have broken it. If so then I cannot see a way around this. If there is definitely no link then I still have a chance.